# How to prevent Snap updates from deleting settings?

Tags: snap, snap-store

When I opened Firefox in Ubuntu 23.04 this week after an update it behaved like a new installation - I had lost all settings and history and had to resync and configure everything from scratch.

I just noticed the same thing happened to Steam today - all my settings have been lost and the games I had installed too - I tried `find | grep` for any filename related to a game and can't find anything.

Why are Snap updates resetting my configuration and how do I stop this please?